# When kids reach a certain age they are shipped off to another planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

The kids are shipped to a different planet to survive for a certain period. I can remember there being a larger kid that had a gun and a dog for protection who ends up dead. In the end, the kids weren't actually shipped off to a different planet, but instead were on Earth the whole time.

I know it is not one of the Heinlein Juveniles books. Can anyone think of anything other than those books?

Comment: I found at least four questions where the answer was 'Tunnel in the Sky".

Comment: Zach, please could you confirm whether the answer below is correct, and "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left if so?

Answer (score 19):

This is Heinlein's [Tunnel in the Sky](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?957) unless he got seriously copied.  The incident with a kid who owns the dog and big gun and gets killed is right out of that novel.

From the [Wikipedia summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_in_the_Sky)

> Rod Walker is a high school student who dreams of becoming a
> professional colonist. The final test of his Advanced Survival class
> is to stay alive on an unfamiliar planet for between two and ten days.
> Students may team up and equip themselves with whatever gear they can
> carry, but are otherwise completely on their own. They are told only
> that the challenges are neither insurmountable nor unreasonable. On
> test day, each student walks through the Ramsbotham portal and finds
> him or herself alone on a strange planet, though reasonably close to
> the pickup point. Rod, acting on his older sister's advice, takes
> hunting knives and basic survival gear rather than high-tech weaponry,
> on the grounds that the latter could make him over-confident. The last
> advice the students receive is to "watch out for stobor."

Here's the part where Rod finds the dead guy:

> It looked mightily like a man on the ground and a child near him.  Rod
> reached, fumbled in his vest pack, got out a tiny 8-power monocular,
> took a better look.  The man was Johann Braun, the "child" was his
> boxer dog.  There was no doubt but that they were dead, for Braun was
> lying like a tossed rag doll, with his head twisted around and one leg
> bent under.  His throat and the side of his head were a dark red
> stain.

The only thing that doesn't match your recollection is the part about them not really being on another planet.  That doesn't happen in *Tunnel in the Sky*, but at one point Rod is convinced that this is the case.  Another kid points out the error in his theory.  This discussion takes place in Chapter 5 "The Nova".